# Nokia N8 - Does it support HID profile?

Tags: symbian, nokia, hid, nokia-n8

I tried submitting the same question to symbain support ticket but no luck as of now. I have made an application that uses Bluetooth HID profile. The application works with my Nokia C6 phone however when it comes to Nokia N8, the application does not connect at all :(. The code is same, i am using Symbian Cube SDK. Just wondering if the application is working fine at C6 then why it is not working on N8.

Thanks

Comment: Well, there are several things you need to clarify starting with: a) what is Symbian Support Ticket and have you given them better info that what is provided here, b) What firmware version do you run on C6 and on N8, c) what is the Symbian Cube SDK (I'm guessing S^3 SDK 0.9 beta) and which particular APIs are you working with and finally, d) what does your debugging show?